# мобильное приложение на nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cordova

Ребят, подскажите пожалуйста, имеется ли возможность написать гибридное приложение на cordova с применением nom пакетов для этого приложения? Может не совсем корректно вопрос звучит, я опишу суть своей проблемы. пишу гибридное приложение для смартов на apache cordova и пришла нужда использовать модуль камеры смартфона со своим интерфейсом камеры. соответственно пришла мысль взять пакет npm для веб-камеры. однако, всем известен тот фак, что nodejs - это бекэнд - меня сильно смущает. просто упаковав приложение для мобильника (тот же андроид - apk файл) и запустив его на своем нтс будет ли работать это приложение?

Comment: Node.js действительно порой используют только для сборки проекта.

Comment: Нет. Модули требуют установки node js на телефон. У кордовы (и фонгэпа) есть встроенная поддержка камеры и получения её изображения: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html

Comment: Хотя чисто по приколу я видел статью, где чувак установил на свой старый смарт ноду (как на обычную убунту), а потом пробросил порт, сделал белый ip и запустил сервак для своего сайта, но это, блин, извращение.

Comment: не,плагин коровы на камеру - фуфло полное. мне нужен свой интерфейс камеры, свои кнопки и настройки =) в том то вся и суть.

Comment: Или делайте страничку со своей камерой и прорисуйте кнопки в инерфейсе с помощью html/css используя камеру в браузере c помощью navigator.getUserMedia(), как тут https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/    или используйте нативный интент камеры:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-intent

Оба варианта слишком сложные, чтобы писать прилагу на кордобе, проще уже нативка.

Answer (score 1):

Не будет. Совет - кроме стандартного кордовского плагина есть же еще js-библиотеки для работы с камерой 
http://bridgeit.github.io/demo-vanilla/menu.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35073984/launch-android-phone-front-camera-by-html5-or-javascript

Comment: Не хлопцы, это все от лукавого... брал cordova-plugin-camera-preview, но это до того тормозное приложение на выходе, что просто атас... ладно, я так, спросил совеьа-мнения знающих гуру.. спасибо. Буду тогда переписывать все под реакт нейтив.

Comment: вот мое гибридное приложение (вроде не тормозит) https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=whatisit.eugeneevstafiev.intel

Comment: На чем писано ? )

Comment: вот еще на ионике https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ionicframework.gubahabrew https://itunes.apple.com/ru/app/gubaha-brewery-%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F/id1220377115?mt=8 https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/store/p/gubaha-brewery/9n3t2jq3h1jn

Comment: Круто! Как вы сделали управление камерой? Через плагин кордовы и navigator.camera.getPicture()? А распознавание через АПИ гугла?

Comment: да, все верно !